# Accessing nested list and dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
B = {1:['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

The answer I need is to get the key from `B` and for each element in its value, which is a list, replace it with its value from `A`, like the following:

```
D = {1:[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: break down the task.  Can you replace an item in a list?  If you can do that, you are on your way...  what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A[B[1][0]] - will give you the value of 'a'

A[B[1][1]] - will give you the value of 'b' and so on...

Here is mt solution:

```js
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

B = {1:['a', 'b', 'c']}

D = {}

for key, value in B.items():
    D[key] = []
    for oneValue in value:
        D[key].append(A[oneValue]);
          
print D;
```

Answer (score 0):

In place editing B:

```
for key in B.keys():
    for i in range(len(B[key])):
        B[key][i] = A[B[key][i]]
```

Create a new D for returning

```
D = B.copy()
for key in D.keys():
    for i in range(len(D[key])):
        D[key][i] = A[D[key][i]]
```

I tested the code and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, Jack, for your answer. The point is that my real B has 25 keys and values and values are lists with different length, and I need to go through all of them. Could you please let me know how can I replace [1] in your code in a proper way to go through all the keys.

Comment: Updated my answer :) you just add another loop outside

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
B = {1:['a', 'b', 'c']}

for key, value in B.items():  # loop in dict B
    # loop in every list in B, use items as key to get values from A
    # default to None if key doesn't exists in A and put it in a new temp list
    l = [A.get(x, None) for x in value]

    # Simplified version of line above
    # l = []
    # for x in value:
    #     l.append(A.get(x, None))

    D[key] = l  # use key of B as key and your new list value and add it to D
```

Or if you like to be too cleaver then:

```
# Doing same things as the last example but in one line
# which is hard to read and understand. Don't do this
D = {k: [A.get(x, None) for x in v] for k, v in B.items()}
```